# Реализация ИИ в стратегических играх

Tags: разработка-игр, искусственный-интеллект, планирование

Мне очень интересно, как в стратегических играх реализуется ИИ. Я уже довольно давно изучаю информацию по этой теме, но пока не нашел идею, которая бы меня впечатлила.

Для примера возьмем следующую абстрактную и сильно упрощенную игру, механика которой основана на механике игры `Dune The Battle for Arrakis (Sega Mega Drive)`:

1. Квадратная плоская карта, например - 1000 x 1000 клеток;
2. По карте разбросаны исчерпаемые ресурсы;
3. Один тип здания - всемогущая база;
4. Один вариант добывающего юнита;
5. Один вариант боевого юнита;
6. Один вариант разведывательного юнита;
7. Туман войны;
8. Расы, управляемые ИИ, могут воевать между собой;
9. ИИ - честный, он подвержен туману войны и недостатку информации, как и настоящий (человеческий) игрок.

Допустим, это все.

Механика игры кажется предельно простой, но даже в этом случае с ИИ возникают проблемы.

Я наивно полагал, что могу переложить хотя бы анализ ситуации и принятие решений на нейронные сети, но я не смог. Потому что для обучения даже простейших вариантов нейронных сетей нужно невообразимое количество данных и ресурсов. То есть, обучение ИИ в стратегии в режиме реального времени невозможно. Абсолютно.

Предварительное обучение тоже невозможно (практически), потому что для этого нужно нечто, вроде миллиона полных реплеев (записей) боев. Даже если использовать для обучения целый вычислительный кластер, то непонятно, где брать реплеи. Для какой-нибудь `Dota2` есть достаточное количество записей боев со всей необходимой статистикой, но что если речь идет о небольшой игре?

То есть, если я захочу сделать ИИ для стратегии, то нейронные сети мне совершенно ничем не помогут.

Вот и получается, что логику и поведение ИИ в стратегии необходимо программировать руками. Возможно, на основе машины состояний. Возможно, с использованием деревьев планирования, стратегии и тактики. Это все чрезвычайно сложно и совершенно меня не вдохновляет.

Я не представляю, как учесть:

- Планирование добычи;
- Разведку;
- Защиту собственной добычи;
- Набеги на вражескую добычу;
- Стратегический захват важной местности;
- Анализ активных боевых действий;
- Устраивание засад;
- Подкрепление для важных направлений;
- Анализ уязвимых мест противника;
- Экономику.

Подскажите, есть ли какие-то альтернативы этому?
<del>Чтобы оно само там как-нибудь все сделалось...</del>

Я буду благодарен за любую информацию.

Comment: В простейшем случае - это может быть простой скрипт из линейной или слабоветвящейся последовательности действий. Пример: сначала делаем N добывающих юнитов, отправляем на добычу. потом делаем разведчика (когда достаточно ресурсов на него), отправляем на разведку. У разведчика свой "интеллект", он просто разведывает все что можно, избегая врага. Дальше клепаем N боевых юнитов, отправляем на базу противника (если она найдена), в бою мочим либо самого сильного, либо самого слабого (в зависимости от выбранной стратегии), своих подбитых юнитов отводим назад, при больших потерях возвращаемся на базу

Comment: И т.д. Если не нужен сверхмощный непобедимый интеллект, то это относительно просто программируется.

Comment: @insolor, это слишком простое решение. Простое не с точки зрения реализации, а с точки зрения поведения. Хотелось бы чего-то, что отдаленно напоминает игру человека, с импровизацией, обучаемостью и правдоподобными ошибками. Видимо, нужно смотреть в сторону автомата, который способен формировать поведение из элементарных шаблонов, вести статистику и подстраиваться.

Comment: @MGNeo вот вы говорите что это решение слишком простое, а мне наоборот кажется, что все решения, которые приходят вам в голову, излишне сложные. начните с простого и усложняйте. представьте, что кто-нибудь даст вам апи к человеческому мозгу. да вы просто не поймёте что с ним делать и как использовать! я считаю, что такие вещи нужно понимать изнутри досконально, по этому они должны быть простыми на ранних этапах разработки.